# Typescript conditional return type for a funciton

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function which can return two types, something like this:

```js
function doSomething(obj: {a: string, b?: string}): string | number {
  if (obj.b) {
    return 'something'
  }
  return 1
}
```

If the function is called with an object containing the optional `b` property, it will always return one type, in this case let's say `string`.

If the function is called with an object that does not contain the optional property `b`, it will always return another type, in this case let say `number`.

Currently, if I call the function the return type will always be the union of `string` and `number`:

```js
const result = doSomething({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
//      ^ string | number
// although we know it is always going to be a string if the `b` property is given
```

Is there a way for the function to return the correct type depending on the argument given to the function?

```js
const result1 = doSomething({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
//      ^ string

const result2 = doSomething({a: 'a'})
//      ^ number
```

I've been trying to do it using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) but haven't succeeded and don't know if I'm on the right direction:

```js
type ConditionalType<T> = T extends { b: string} ? string : number
type Argument = {
  a: string,
  b?: string,
}

function doSomething<T extends Argument>(obj: T): ConditionalType<T> {
  if (obj.b) {
    return 'something' // type string is not assignable to ConditionalType<T>
  }
  return 1 // type number is not assignable to ConditionalType<T>
}

const result = doSomething({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
```

Also tried letting TypeScript infer the type but the result is still an union type:

```js
function doSomething(obj: {a:string,b?:string}) {
  if (obj.b) {
    return 'something'
  }
  return 1
}

const result = doSomething({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
//      ^ "something" | 1
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFHAEYBWAXIgN4CG1AzlAE6FEA05A-C+04BfAJT0AUIkQxgiMlQB05MXUlTEbXCDZIA5Myy4CxXWqFrNUbUgCM48+IgJWG7MxAAbKDcQBeFOiG+JwkjLS6DLpciOTh5Lqi4gD0SerqAHqIAEQGOMHEWYgAPoh2js5Qru5eAEx+ARh5xqRhiBEJIsmpaYiZOUHNhSU2QA)

Comment: Here's the closest I've got: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFHAEYBWAXIgN4CG1AzlAE6FEA05L7nAXwCUtVh2IBuAFChIsBCnRZcBYmSq1Gfcd17hk2YIWzJhtMCEzlsbabOjwkqDDnyd1NekzGce2zogAPoj6hsamIog+xIEWVjb0UoiIMMCIHgB05EKJyclsuCBsSADkzMpuxCVJiAI1BVBFSACMUnVSEAisiAXMIAA2UM2IALyKLiruWoglDCVciLwz5CXCUgD063l5AHqIAETlrqpE+0GIrZ1g5f3YGf1wpL0DQ0LSHV1QPdh9gwBMo3GFROJGms3mi1ooSMYBMa0222Se0OwM4Z2Cly6cFu90eJGe-zeQA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. It's pure function overloading:

```
function doSomething(obj: {a:string,b?:string}): string;
function doSomething(obj: {a:string,b?:undefined}): number;
function doSomething(obj: {a:string,b?:string}): string|number {
  if (obj.b) {
    return 'something'
  }
  return 1
}

const result1 = doSomething({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
//      ^ "something" | 1
console.log(result1);

const result2 = doSomething({a: 'a'})
//      ^ "something" | 1
console.log(result2);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFHAEYBWAXIgN4CG1AzlAE6FEA05A-C%2004BfAJS1WHYgG4AUKEiwEKdFlwFiZKrUYDJ3PtXDJswQtmSjaYEJnLY2s%20dHhJUGHPk6aa9JhM48-P7ElojBRAA%201rb29DKIiDDAiN4AdOQicQkJbLggbEgA5MyqnsSF8YhClblQ%20UgAjDLVMhAIrIi5zCAANlANiAC8yu5qXjqIhQyFXIjktIXkhaIyAPSr2dkAeogARCUe6kS7iBGITW1gJT3YqT1wpF29-SKyre1QndjdfQBMQyNSkcSBMpssRGsNptEDt9kDOCczhd2nAbncHiQnn9XkA)